# Exception: 'IValueConverter' type does not have a public TypeConverter class

Tags: wpf, ivalueconverter

I have just run into this exception on an IValueConverter I am implementing:

> IValueConverter type does not have a
>   public TypeConverter class

Has anyone else come across this? What's the cause, and how do I fix? Thanks.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Simple solution, as it turns out. I had referenced my value converter like this:

```
<Binding Path="Foreground" Converter="StaticResource BrushToRgbConverter" ConverterParameter="B" />
```

instead of this:

```
<Binding Path="Foreground" Converter="{StaticResource BrushToRgbConverter}" ConverterParameter="B" />
```

In other words, I had omitted the braces from my `Converter` reference.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me out!  WPF sometimes has the strangest errors!

Comment: I hate it when I forget the braces.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [an article I wrote](http://www.developingfor.net/wpf/brush-type-does-not-have-a-public-typeconverter-class.html) about the same problem, but with a different cause.  In my case, I had referenced the wrong Brush class in the wrong namespace.